# I am new to making bots and idk what to do it says Syntax: Error: 'await' outside function

Tags: python

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

if message.content.startswith('$rank'):
  await message.channel.send('hi')

client.run(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Expected:
We have logged in as #Botname

Happened:
File "main.py", line 16
await message.channel.send('hi')
^
Syntax Error: 'await' outside function

Comment: Looks like an indentation error. Your 2 `if` tests should be at the same level, inside the function, but the second one is outside the function (because it is wrongly outdented). As the message says.

Answer (score 0):

In python, tabs and spaces are important, if you don't put enough tabs/spaces, python will think your statement isn't inside a function. Look carefully at your code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

if message.content.startswith('$rank'):
  await message.channel.send('hi')
```

You are missing a tab/4 spaces before the second `if` and second `await`, so python think that the if statement isn't in the async function, thus it warns that you can't use await. To fix this, index your code correctly like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('$rank'):
    await message.channel.send('hi')
```